# Cannot call abstract method interface in Service-Repository pattern

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel9 project, I have many controllers that have similar functions like:

TestController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Contracts\TestInterface;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(
        private TestInterface $testService,
        private $moduleName = 'Test Name',
    ) {}

    public function index()
    {
        $tests = $this->testService->index();
        $response      = response([
            'message' => __('Read' . $this->moduleName . 'successfully'),
            'data'    => $tests,
        ], 200);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Test1Controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Contracts\Test1Interface;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class Test1Controller extends ApiController
{
    public function __construct(
        private Test1Interface $test1Service,
        private $moduleName = 'Test Name 1',
    ) {}

    public function index()
    {
        $test1s = $this->test1Service->index();
        $response      = response([
            'message' => __('Read' . $this->moduleName . 'successfully'),
            'data'    => $test1s,
        ], 200);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

So I modified them into:

TestController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Contracts\TestInterface;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiController;

class TestController extends ApiController
{
    protected function service()
    {
        return TestInterface::class;
    }
}
```

Test1Controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Contracts\Test1Interface;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiController;

class Test1Controller extends ApiController
{
    protected function service() 
    {
        return Test1Interface::class;
    }
}
```

ApiController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

abstract class ApiController extends Controller
{
    private $serviceClass;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->serviceClass = $this->service();
    }

    abstract protected function service();

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->serviceClass::index();
    }
}
```

TestInterface.php

```
namespace App\Contracts;

interface TestInterface extends BaseInterface
{
    
}
```

BaseInterface.php

```
namespace App\Contracts;

interface BaseInterface
{
    public function index();
}
```

Then I bind interfaces into services in AppServiceProvider.php, like:

```
$this->app->bind('App\Contracts\TestInterface', 'App\Services\TestService');
$this->app->bind('App\Contracts\Test1Interface', 'App\Services\Test1Service');
```

TestService.php:

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\TestInterface;
use App\Repositories\TestRepository;

class TestService implements TestInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private TestRepository $testRepo,
    ) {}

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->testRepo->index();
    }
}
```

Test1Service.php

```
namespace App\Services;

use App\Contracts\Test1Interface;
use App\Repositories\Test1Repository;

class Test1Service implements Test1Interface
{
    public function __construct(
        private Test1Repository $test1Repo,
    ) {}

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->test1Repo->index();
    }
}
```

When I call TestController::index on my route, I get:

> Cannot call abstract method App\Contracts\TestInterface::index()

How can I fix it or do any better suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I don’t really understand what you are specifically doing, but `class Test1Controller extends ApiController
{
    protected function service() {
        return Test1Interface::class;
    }
}` feels wrong. Generally you start abstract and work your way to concrete, for instance you ask for an interface and return a class or object. But this is a specific subclass and instance returning something abstract and non-invocable. I could totally be missing something, however.

Comment: But I have bound it from AppServiceProvider and it should return TestService normally right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the problem by modifying the following line in ApiController.php:

```
private $serviceClass;

public function __construct(
    private Container $app,
)
{
    $this->serviceClass = $app->make($this->service());
}
```